# learning getjson

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get a grasp on using `$.getJSON` with an array from PHP.

Here's a simple example where all I want to do is output the requested info. Should the `alert(data)` return the array object? I am not alerting anything.

PHP file (account.php):

```
$arr = array('items' => 5,'others' => 6); 
echo $arr = json_encode($arr)
```

HTML file:

```
$("#unsubscribe").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("account.php?", function(data) { 
        alert(data);    
    });
});
```

Comment: try : php > $arr = array('items' => 5,'others' => 6); 
php > $arr =  json_encode($arr);
php > echo $arr;
{"items":5,"others":6}

Comment: use $.post and return a var that's value is json encoded. then iterate through it as if its an object... `data.items, data.others`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's probably a good idea if you try to load `account.php` in your browser. You should expect to see:

```
{"items":5,"others":6}
```

However, you won't see this. You will instead see a Parse Error, expected `;`. Because you forgot it on the `echo` line.

This is why you see no `alert`. A PHP error is clearly not valid JSON, and viewing the browser's error console would tell you this ;)

Comment: to add to this, `alert(data)` will alert `[object]` try `alert(data.items+' '+data.others)`

Comment: @Kolink and Mike, the array at account.php is exactly what I see. I get no alert at all, even [object], so I amm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: @stevenpepe Change your Javascript to `$(document).ready(function() { $("#unsubscribe").click(function() { alert('Click fired'); $.getJSON("account.php?", function(data, status, xhr) {
alert(status); alert(xhr.status); alert(data); }); }); });` and tell us what you see. If you don't see any alerts at all, the problem is with your click handler.

Comment: @DaveRandom, the handler works, with both my alert and yours, just no success output.

Comment: @stevenpepe Try with the long-hand `$.ajax` version (the [jQ docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) show what the equivalent is) and supply an `error:` handler - `$.getJSON` only allows you to supply a `success:` handler. If `error:` fires, it will be easier to find and fix the problem, so that `$.getJSON` will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I am using dump function for viewing json returned array.
Here it is:

```
function dump(arr,level) {
var dumped_text = "";
if(!level) level = 0;

//The padding given at the beginning of the line.
var level_padding = "";
for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
    for(var item in arr) {
        var value = arr[item];

        if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
            dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "'"+"\\n";
            if (level < 0)
                dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
        } else {
            dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => '" + value + "'"+"\\n";
        }
    }
} else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
    dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
}
return dumped_text;
}
```